# Symfony4 encode password in Security Folder

Tags: symfony, security, authentication, hash, symfony4

I'm doing a authentication with guard feature. Problem is than I have to put a password to my User, he don't have to know this password so I choose to generate a random password. Problem is than I'm not in a controller so I can't use UserPasswordEncoderInterface ... So I'm looking for some help here.

I give you some code :

```
 public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    /**
     * @var FacebookUser $facebookUser
     */
    $facebookUser = $this->getFacebookClient()
        ->fetchUserFromToken($credentials);

    $email = $facebookUser->getEmail();

    $user = $this->em->getRepository('App:User')
        ->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);
    if (!$user) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail($facebookUser->getEmail());
        $user->setName($facebookUser->getFirstName());
        $user->setLastName($facebookUser->getLastName());
        $user->setRoles(["ROLE_USER"]);

        //TODO HASH PASSWORD

        $user->setPassword(bin2hex(random_bytes(80)));
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    return $user;
}
```

and the method from controller

```
/**
 * After going to Facebook, you're redirected back here
 * because this is the "redirect_route" you configured
 * in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml
 * @Route("/connect/facebook/check", name="connect_facebook_check")
 *
 * @return JsonResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function connectCheckAction() {
    if (!$this->getUser()) {
        return new JsonResponse(array('status' => false, 'message' => "User not found!"));
    } else {
//            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
//
//            $user = $this->getUser();
//            $password = bin2hex(random_bytes(80));
//            $hash = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $password);
//            $user->setPassword($hash);
//
//            $em->persist($user);
//            $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('default');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject EncoderFactoryInterface by constructor:

```
/**
 * @var EncoderFactoryInterface
 */
private $securityEncoderFactory;

public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $securityEncoderFactory)
{
    $this->securityEncoderFactory = $securityEncoderFactory;
}
```

And then use:

```
$encoder = $this->securityEncoderFactory->getEncoder($user);
$encoder->encodePassword($user, $password);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the PHP's function `password_hash` to hash your randomly generated password. See the documentation [here](http://php.net/password_hash)

Comment: Bad bad bad idea.  At least in the Symfony environment.  The password encoder is there for a reason.  Inject it and use it.

Comment: @Cerad Why? I agree that normally injecting and using a password encoder is a better idea, but in this particular case using password_hash seems to be ok. The encoders use this function internally as well.

Comment: Except that there are a number of available options for password_hash as well as for other hashing approaches.  The default options tend to change over time.  With a Symfony password encoder you can be confident that the hashing won't change unless you specifically configure it to.  Having password_hash buried in the bowels of your code while the rest of the system uses the encoder is just asking for long term headaches.